# Удаление (очистка) куки при открытии страницы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
суть проблемы:
  необходимо удалять куки при заходе на страницу,

```
setcookie ("template", "", time() - 360000);
```

работает, но при заходе на страницу верстка (которая висит на этом куки) сохраняется, и приходится еще раз обновить страницу что бы он окончательно очистил куки и применил параметры страницы..

Comment: Что значит `верстка висит`? 

    $_COOKIE = array();

Если так?

Comment: Массив куки формируется при запросе и не зависит от посланных заголовков (тем более что реально пользователю посылается *запрос на установление данных*, пусть и просроченный), поэтому только очистка руками, как @Smash написал.

Comment: верстка, значит на той странице в куках храниться id стиля, на следующей, стиль по умолчанию 1. ну и при переходе из за куки он его перебивает.
 @Smash  спасибо, вроде работает, щас еще проверю  где нить на стороне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помните, как происходит HTTP запрос-ответ? Сначала браузер "звонит" серверу и говорит, "хочу ту страницу, вот у меня есть такие-то куки". Сервер в ответ думает, и отвечает. Сначала заголовок ответа, в т.ч. установка новых кук. Затем html тело страницы.

Т.о. надо первым делом принять куки, потом установить или сбросить их, затем выдать html, чтобы всё произошло за один запрос-ответ.

Не знаю точно, какова логика вашего приложения, но постарайтесь в самом начале сбросить куки: в браузере, и в принятом значении, для последующей обработки, как будто они пришли пустые:

```
setcookie ('template', '', 1); // сбросит куки в браузере
unset( $_COOKIE[ 'template']); // сбросит ранее принятое от браузера значение
```